# typed variant of `__builtin_assume_aligned` in GNU GCC?

Tags: c++, gnu

GNU provides a function `void * __builtin_assume_aligned(void *, int)` that tells the compiler that it is safe to assume that the pointer input (and returned from) the function is aligned by `N` bytes. However, it returns a `void *`, meaning that I have to cast the returned result, i.e.

```
float *example = (float *) __builtin_assume_aligned(example_aligned, 64);
```

or

```
float *example = std::reinterpret_cast<float *>
                 (__builtin_assume_aligned(example_aligned, 64));
```

Both of these feel like a C/C++-style approach (i.e., someone coding C++ with C style code). Is there a C++ equivalent to `__builtin_assume_aligned`, or am I being too picky?

Comment: when talking about byte alignment, it's just bytes, hence the void pointer. Of course you need to cast it to use it (just like you do with the result of say "malloc").

Yes, you are being really picky over a non-issue

Comment: this is part of C++, you have to cast the RHS of this expression.

The exact error would be "cannot initialize a variable of type 'float *' with an rvalue of type 'void *'"

Comment: you could write your own type-invariant wrapper around this using a C++ template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kebno suggested, a template wrapper can help:

```
template<typename T>
T * assume_aligned(T * p, size_t a, int m = 0)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<T *>(__builtin_assume_aligned(p, a, m));
}
```

Furthermore, it's probably only useful if `a` (and `m`? I have never used the third parameter) are constant, which would furthermore allow you to check for some invariants:

```
template<size_t a, int m = 0, typename T>
T * assume_aligned(T * p)
{
    static_assert(a >= alignof(T));
    static_assert(is_pow2(a));
    return reinterpret_cast<T *>(__builtin_assume_aligned(p, a, m));
}
```

While it doesn't remove the need to cast, it limits the scope to exactly one spot.